# Is rep recalculation not instant for deletions?

Tags: support, reputation

I deleted my old post containing an [outdated answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/whats-the-fastest-way-to-earn-mana) (10k+ only) since there's a newer and better answer, but I haven't lost my rep from it yet (110).  When will that rep fix occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When will that rep fix occur?

Never, in this case. Reputation from deleted posts is usually recalculated within a couple minutes (5-ish), but you won't lose any from that post specifically, because it qualifies for the *special treatment*.

See the blog post [Reputation and Historical Archives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> [...] if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you
>   should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets
>   deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Your post had a score of 11 and was visible for 6 months before you deleted it, so you get to keep your rep.

Comment: I see, I guess that's something new they put in along with the other rep change stuff

Comment: I thought the "special treatment" didn't apply if you deleted your own stuff. Hmmm.

Comment: @Juan Special treatment just applies evenly. Otherwise, we'll start having exceptions to our exceptions to our exceptions... yadda recursion yadda.